# How to set the font size used when replying to an email in text format in Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird

I'd like to increase the font size used in Thunderbird when replying to an email in **text format**. I don't see any such an option in Tools/Options. Is there any way to set this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will set the size on your `plain text` emails when replying:

> Tools > Options > Display > Formatting

Then head down to the **Fonts & Encodings** section and click **Fonts...**

The Fonts & Encodings dialog will pop up.

Head down to the Monospace line and adjust the **Size (pixels)** on the far right.

[image: fonts and encodings dialog]

Click **OK** on the dialog. Then click **OK** on the Options popup.

Now when you reply to an email, and you have the default mode to send out in `plain text`, the font will display in the adjusted size.

If you want to read in a larger font, adjust the value in the **Minimum font size...** setting of the Fonts & Encoding dialog.

Comment: The setting you described only effects the font size when writing new email in my Thunderbird. It does not change the font size neither when reading nor when replying.

Comment: Have taken that little oversight into account and updated the answer to increase the font size across the board.